# What's a good web based FTP service

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm on the move a lot and can't always bring my laptop with me, but would still like to work on my website. There are some web based FTP clients out there but none to my liking. So, I'm looking for something like [net2ftp.com](http://net2ftp.com), but with a better editing environment, like [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Does anyone know of such a service?

Comment: What other web-based solutions have you ruled out and why?  Just so we don't recommend things you've already tried

Comment: Really only have tried net2ftp. I'm looking for an actual web application, not something I have to stick on a flash drive.

Comment: Monsta FTP. It's free to download from https://www.monstaftp.com (disclaimer: I'm involved with this project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got a different possibility.  It's not a third-party service (all I've found look to be clones of net2ftp), but a web-based editor you could install on your own site and use from there: [Webpad](http://dentedreality.com.au/projects/webpad/).  I know it's still not quite what you asked, but it should fulfill the requirement of not needing to bring anything with you.  It does also support opening files via FTP among other things if you wanted to install it on a separate server.

Edit: decided to have one more go at this after bobdias's comment and turned up a couple more options.  The magic google turned out to be *web-based source code editor*. Newest to oldest:

- [Squad](https://squadedit.com/) (non-free)
- [ecoder](http://ecoder.quintalinda.com)
- [CodePress](http://codepress.sourceforge.net/index.php)

This article about [Bespin](http://thenextweb.com/2009/02/13/bespin-web-based-code-editor-mozilla-labs/) looks promising but the bespin website doesn't work for me right now.

Comment: as a bonus, you wouldn't have to give your login credentials to an unknown third party

Comment: Another bonus is that the last version was released in 2005, that's not very good.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://portableapps.com/.  You can get a prepackaged, portable version of FileZilla to run on a flash drive, along with lots of other handy apps for working on the go.  Their platform makes it really easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the net2ftp.com interface on a bunch of sites, and therefore don't trust it.  IMO, you'd be better off bringing an FTP client on a USB stick, or even firing up a copy of a command line FTP session ('ftp' in either windows or linux).

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use FileZilla on a USB stick (see [this](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Client_Installation#With_zip_version)). This would allow you to use a robust FTP client everywhere, while still mainting account names and passwords locally and taking them with you wherever you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FireFTP](http://fireftp.mozdev.org/).

> FireFTP is a **free, secure, cross-platform FTP/SFTP client** for Mozilla Firefox which provides easy and intuitive access to FTP/SFTP servers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some open source ftp clients/file managers you can run on your website's server. I picked the best looking ones that are still being actively developed.

- [AjaXplorer](http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/)
- [OSFileManager](http://www.osfilemanager.com/)
- [FileManager](http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/)
- [FileThingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/)

As for a better editing environment, try [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or another Javascript code editor; Wikipedia has a great [list of Javascript code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors).